# How do I set up a test Facebook account?

Tags: facebook, user-accounts

We have developed a website that allows users to subscribe to a service using their Facebook credentials.

How do we create test Facebook accounts that can be used to execute end-user test cases for this feature?

Comment: You can create test users at `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/roles`

Comment: **To clarify** - creating "fake" test accounts is supported by Facebook for the purpose of testing an application.  The down votes on this post are slightly exaggerated...

Answer (score 3):

You can create test users via the Graph API. You shouldn't refer to them as "fake" users because that has some negative connotations; Facebook actively peruses and shut's down fake accounts. I believe what you are talking about though is accounts to test Facebook applications...

The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/) details how to create test users via the api -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/accounts/test-users?
  installed=true
  &name=FULL_NAME
  &locale=en_US
  &permissions=read_stream
  &method=post
  &access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

You'll need to substitute all your own data in the request and the response you'll get back should look something like this -

```
{ 
  "id": "1234...",  
  "access_token":"1234567..." , 
  "login_url":"https://www.facebook.com/platform/test_account..."
  "email": "example...@tfbnw.net",
  "password": "1234..."
}
```

You can then use that users credentials to test your applications authentication process and functionality.

In addition to creating test accounts via the api, you can also use the interface within the application's dashboard under the "Roles" section - `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP_ID/roles`

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Had  the test accounts set up with no problem. Finally found the parameter I was missing to get the accounts to interact with the website properly.

Cheers.